# Lennard Jones Clusters in Python

Tags: molecular-dynamics, software-recommendations, python, geometry-optimization, jax-md

I would like to explore the global optimisation of Lennard-Jones clusters in Python. I do not come from a physical chemistry background. I would like to be able to calculate the cluster energy pointwise. That is, I would like a python function $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which I can use to test my methods on.

Do there exist simple python packages that have this functionality, or how can the clusters be implemented in python?

Comment: Check out the codes/software that uses Jax. https://github.com/google/jax-md a year or two ago when I first looked at it, it only did Lennard-Jones, but it looks like the author has really put alot of work into it.

Answer (score 4):

## Potential

The [Lennard-Jones potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) has a simple form:
$$ V_{\rm LJ} (r) = 4\epsilon \left[ \left( \frac \sigma r \right)^{12} - \left( \frac \sigma r \right)^{6} \right]. $$
In python, this could be

```
def V_LJ(r, epsilon, sigma):
    '''Computes the Lennard-Jones potential'''
    return 4.0*epsilon*((sigma/r)**12 - (sigma/r)**6)
```

## Application

To apply this potential, you just need to calculate
$$ f = \sum_{i<j} V_{\rm LJ}(R_{ij}) $$
where $R_{ij}$ is the distance between atoms $i$ and $j$. Assume that your coordinates are in a numpy array
`coords = numpy.zeros((3,Natoms))`. Then, you can compute $R_{ij}$ as `Rij = numpy.linalg.norm(coords[i]-coords[j])`.

Evaluation of the full potential energy would then be

```
def LJ_potential(atoms):
 '''Computes Lennard-Jones potential for atoms'''
Natoms = atoms.shape[1]
f = 0.0
for i in range(Natoms):
    for j in range(i):
        Rij = numpy.linalg.norm(coords[i]-coords[j])
        f += V_LJ(Rij, epsilon, sigma)
return f
```

## Gradient methods

Note that the function also has a simple gradient
$$ \frac {dV_{\rm LJ}} {dr} (r) = \frac {4\epsilon} {\sigma} \left[ -12  \left( \frac \sigma r \right)^{13} + 6 \left( \frac \sigma r \right)^{7} \right], $$
so you can also use gradient descent methods for optimization, or molecular dynamics methods.